# On the go visualization with Tkinter Canvas Widget

Tags: python, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to implement a visualisation for IoT project using Tkinker Canvas Widget.

[image]

What I'm **not** trying to do is making an animation using something like this:

```
def animate(self):
    self.__draw_one_frame()
    self.master.after(120, self.animate())
```

And:

```
mainloop()
```

To run the animation.

What I **am** trying to do is making synchronous request and update on the widget, like this:

1. draw() method is run externally
2. Canvas is updated with new animation

I've had really hard time doing this, and I would really appreciate some hints or somebody telling me that it cannot be done with Tkinker and recommending me some other library.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution over here:
[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4836121/3629229)

Apparently there is a method `root.update()` which refreshes the canvas on demand.